# Laravel Database Session not storing user provider

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a laravel system with multiple user providers. (For example user and admin)

I use database to store sessions (.env SESSION_DRIVER=database)

When I want to delete all sessions for a current user, i can't because laravel only stores the user_id but not stores the provider (like App/Models/Admin, App/Models/User).

If I delete sessions where user_id = 1, then it could be also an admin and a user.

Does anybody have a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could create your custom database session driver by extending the internal [`DatabaseSessionHandler`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.8.4/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php) to add the additional information you need. You can check the [Session Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#adding-custom-session-drivers) to see the requirements for implementing a custom session driver.